# How to calculate total jumlahtrx in textView which get from json

Tags: php, android, json

> [{"id":"4","jenistrx":"masuk","keterangantrx":"masssuakn","jumlahtrx":"50000","tgltrx":"2017-11-25 23:45:06"},{"id":"5","jenistrx":"keluar","keterangantrx":"keluar","jumlahtrx":"20000","tgltrx":"2017-11-25 23:45:27"},{"id":"6","jenistrx":"keluar","keterangantrx":"biaya","jumlahtrx":"5000","tgltrx":"2017-11-26 08:22:38"}]

I want to calculate sum of total "jumlahtrx" sum which is get from php, I am using JsonArray.

at top of my class

```
int Saldo = 0;
```

Then

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {
            // Passing HTTP URL to HttpServicesClass Class.
            HttpServicesClass httpServicesClass = new HttpServicesClass(HttpUrl);
            try
            {
                httpServicesClass.ExecutePostRequest();

                if(httpServicesClass.getResponseCode() == 200)
                {
                    JSonResult = httpServicesClass.getResponse();

                    if(JSonResult != null)
                    {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                        try {
                            jsonArray = new JSONArray(JSonResult);
                            int sumTotaljumlah = 0;

                            JSONObject jsonObject;

                            Student student;

                            studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                            {
                                student = new Student();

                                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                //String jenis = jsonObject.getString("jenistrx");
                                String total = jsonObject.getString("jumlahtrx");
                                sumTotaljumlah = Integer.parseInt(total);
                                Saldo = Saldo + sumTotaljumlah;

                                // Adding Student Id TO IdList Array.
                                IdList.add(jsonObject.getString("id").toString());

                                //Adding Student Name.
                                student.JenisTrx = jsonObject.getString("jenistrx").toString();
                                student.JumlahTrx = jsonObject.getString("jumlahtrx").toString();
                                studentList.add(student);

                            }

                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, httpServicesClass.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Here is how to show

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

{
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    StudentListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    TextView textViewTotal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTotal);
    textViewTotal.setText("Saldo: Rp. "+Saldo);
    ListAdapterClass adapter = new ListAdapterClass(studentList, context);

    StudentListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Any fix for this?

Comment: java's basics: variable's scopes...

Comment: why are you using "String payment = c.getString("jumlahtrx");"  ,  what does 'c' means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `sum` variable at the Activity level (not inside your AsyncTask) :

```
public class YourActivity extends ...{
   int sum = 0;
```

Then sum the values

```
  String payment = jsonObject.getString("jumlahtrx");
                                Totaljumlah = Integer.parseInt(payment);
                                sum = sum+Totaljumlah;
```

Finally, set the value in your textview:

```
        TextView textViewTotal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTotal);
        textViewTotal.setText("" + sum);
```

Comment: I'm glad to help you

Comment: can i ask one question? can we have an "if" statement, for example if "jenistrx = masuk" then "sum = sum+Totaljumlah" elseif "jenistrx = keluar" then "sum = sum-Totaljumlah" . Can we?

Comment: Yes, if you can but you need to know how to compare strings in java

Comment: thanks, i created exactly inside of sum and it's work, thanks

Comment: i think, we have some problem here, when i try to add more database it's not showing, only 2 data show and change "sum" value, any fix?

Comment: edit my first post, my result json have 3 data but when I run it, it only show 2 data

Comment: I think the error is from my database, because the value, I will check it and update

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you have to use

```
json_decode($yourresponse)
```

To retrieve the array.

Then, you use to get

```
$1 = $yourresponse[0]["jumlahtrx"]
$2 = $yourresponse[1]["jumlahtrx"];
```

and maybe

```
bcadd($1,$2);
```

etc.